# Difference between subquery or group by for a max statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know the difference between this two statemens.

Group by statement:

```
SELECT 
   a,
   max(b)
from table
group by a;
```

Subquery statement:

```
SELECT 
   a,
   b
from table as t1
where b=(SELECT MAX(b) from table as t2 where t1.a=t2.a);
```

The goal of both statements is to show for single `a` value the `max(b)` .

Comment: Different queries, returning different results... Create the table, insert some sample table data and verify the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

First approach will give you the maximum value of `b` irrespective of row. Like what if you have 3 columns `a`,`b` and `c` and using first approach `a` will be grouping criteria and for `b` you will get max value but what about `c` which value you will get it depends on mysql, it will not give you the row where `b`'s value is maximum

```
a  b  c
1  3  2 
1  2  4
1  1  6
```

While using second approach it will give you those rows where `b`'s value is maximum considering above data set you will get 1,3,2.

In other words first one will give max value of `b` per `a` group and second approach will give the maximum row per `a` group

Answer (score 0):

in first part `max()` return maximum value of b from each group.

in second part you just search for max b and get according lines

Answer (score 0):

here we go with the results of both:

**first of all you need to create a table to test those:**

```
create table #table1
(
a int,
--region nvarchar(1),
b int
)

insert into #table1 values(1,2);
insert into #table1 values(3,4);
insert into #table1 values(5,2);
insert into #table1 values(4,7);
insert into #table1 values(7,3);
```

then run both the queries you will get the result in attached image.
[image]

do let me know if you need any more help

Comment: It would be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about what these 2 queries do and the difference between (this was the question)

Comment: for query 1  - It will return two columns a,b with max of b values however due to group by on a column result-set got grouped for a.

Comment: for query 2 - when maximum value of b selected on condition where  value from a is equal to b of max(b). You can clearly see that from image.